# how to fix cassandra debug.log error LEAK: ByteBuf.release()

Tags: cassandra

I am getting this error in my debug file.If anybody knows this error please help to solve it. Frustated with this error

ERROR [epollEventLoopGroup-2-51] 2017-11-09 16:09:21,495 Slf4JLogger.java:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel() See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.

I am using G1 garbage collector instead of CMS collector

I have 4 servers

x.x.x.1 contains-------------------------------------------

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="8G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="2000M"

OS: CentOS - 7
RAM: 142 GB
Swap: 3 GB
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
Core: 40 Core
Disk: 2.5T

x.x.x.2 contains--------------------------------------------

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="4000M"

OS: CentOS - 7
RAM: 125 GB
Swap: 3 GB
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
Core: 40 Core
Disk: 2.2T

x.x.x.3 contains---------------------------------------------

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="16G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="4000M"

OS: CentOS - 7
RAM: 125 GB
Swap: 3 GB

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz
Core: 40 Core
Disk: 2 TB

x.x.x.4 contains-----------------------------------------

MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="1200M"

OS: CentOS - 7
RAM: 125 GB
Swap: 3 GB
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Core: 12 Core
Disk: 2.7 TB

jvm options are like this----------------------

-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70

-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16

-XX:ConcGCThreads=16

log options are like this -----------------------

-XX:+PrintGCDetails

-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps

-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC

-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure

-XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1

-Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log

-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation

-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10

-XX:GCLogFileSize=10M

but thing is one of the server is always turns down.

Thanks and Regards

pavs

Comment: What Cassandra version are you using?

Comment: 3.9.0 and os is centos